# Issue with Dojo/Dijit and blank option in form select

Tags: dojo, html-select, spring-roo

I am very new to Dojo and I am running into the following issue.

I have the following form select generated by spring roo:

```html
<div id="_f_trc_suivi_domain_Pli_conteneurNum_id">
            <label for="_conteneurNum_id">Conteneur Num : </label>
            <select id="_conteneurNum_id" name="conteneurNum">
            <option value="">Tous</option>
                <option value="1">951</option>
                <option value="2">753</option>
                <option value="3">753159</option></select><br />
            <script type="text/javascript">
                Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({
                    elementId : '_conteneurNum_id',
                    widgetType : 'dijit.form.FilteringSelect',
                    widgetAttrs : {
                        hasDownArrow : true
                    }
                }));
            </script>
        </div>
```

which results in the following in firebug:

```html
<div wairole="combobox" dojoattachpoint="comboNode"
    id="widget__conteneurNum_id"
    class="dijit dijitReset dijitInlineTable dijitLeft dijitTextBox dijitComboBox dijitTextBoxError dijitComboBoxError dijitError"
    role="combobox" widgetid="_conteneurNum_id"
    aria-labelledby="_conteneurNum_id_label" aria-expanded="false">
    <div dojoattachevent="onmousedown:_onArrowMouseDown"
        wairole="presentation" dojoattachpoint="downArrowNode"
        class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer"
        role="presentation">
        <input type="text" wairole="presentation" readonly="" tabindex="-1"
            value="? " class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner"
            role="presentation">
    </div>
    <div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer">
        <input type="text" wairole="presentation" readonly="" tabindex="-1"
            value="? "
            class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner"
            role="presentation">
    </div>
    <div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer">
        <input type="text" waistate="haspopup-true,autocomplete-list"
            wairole="textbox" dojoattachpoint="textbox,focusNode"
            dojoattachevent="onkeypress:_onKeyPress,compositionend"
            autocomplete="off" class="dijitReset dijitInputInner"
            role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-autocomplete="list"
            id="_conteneurNum_id" tabindex="0" aria-required="true"
            aria-invalid="true" value="" aria-owns="_conteneurNum_id_popup"><input
            type="hidden" name="conteneurNum" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

but unfortunately, it always displays a **white option** above the blank option whose value is "Tous".

See following gif:

[image: resulting form field]

What I am getting wrong? Any clue welcome.

**EDIT**: I know for certain the problem lies with this: `<option value="">Tous</option>` especially the `value=""` part. I can rephrase and refine my question as follows: how can I make sure Dojo/Dijit deals properly with this: `value=""`??

Comment: use dijit.form.Select instead of FilteringSelect

Comment: I did consider that but I'd like to understand why this issue happens and how this component works especially bearing in mind that when there are no blank option in the select, the select is displayed properly.

Comment: did you try to set a value for the 1st option?
Also why not setting the data-dojo-type directly as here?
<select data-dojo-type="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" id="fruit" name="fruit">
    <option value="AP">Apples</option>
    <option value="OR" selected>Oranges</option>
    <option value="PE" >Pears</option>
</select>

Comment: Hello Unludo, my select is decorated with dojo by spring and I need a null value for the first option...Any other idea?

Comment: can you just try without spring decoration and rather the data-dojo-ype attribute?

Comment: Unfortunately it is very impossible to add this attribute to my Spring  form:select tag...

Comment: My mistake!! It is possible. I'll try and post here accordingly.

Comment: I tried adding the `data-dojo-type="dijit.form.FilteringSelect` but it does not seem to be picked up by the Firefox and my select is rendered as a plain field...

Comment: you could also try to remove the option with empty value and see if it works. For this option you could also try with no value attribute at all.

Comment: Regarding the first point: it does work fine if the option with the empty attribute is removed. About the second point it is not possible to remove the value attribute with spring form unfortunately.

Comment: can you hack by adding javascript?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
                          dojo.require('dojo/dom');
                          dojo.ready(function remAttr(){
                           dojo.removeAttr('theId', 'value');
                         }
                         );
      </script>` results in Could not load 'dom'; last tried '../dom.js'` Any idea?

Comment: why not trying to put value="NULL" and manage a specific case?

Comment: Regarding removing the value attribute, I opened another post to which you kindly replied. I'll let you know what the result is when I get it to work.

Comment: @Unludo. I am now realizing that it is impossible to remove the value attribute from the `<option...` tag because Dojo/Spring has already changed the select into something else (see second code listing in the post above). Any other idea?

Comment: @balteo You may use addOption, removeOption methods on diji.form.select to manipulate the options. You access the dijit through dijit.byId("_conteneurNum_id")

Comment: @Unludo Good point. I tried but it does not work. see here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MVCTA/1/)

Comment: @balteo try this one http://jsfiddle.net/jpJwN/ Click an option in the first select to add the empty value

Comment: I systematically get a `dijit.byId("_conteneurNum_id").addOption is not a function`?!?

Comment: your fiddle has a select which is not a dijit.

Comment: I mean in my local app not the fiddle one.

Comment: That means that when you execute this command, _conteneurNum_id is not a dijit.

Comment: I see... However I am pretty sure I have set it up to be a dijit.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the 0 value there as expected. I have no issues with the following code:

```
<div id="_f_trc_suivi_domain_Pli_conteneurNum_id">
        <label for="_conteneurNum_id">Conteneur Num : </label>
        <select id="_conteneurNum_id" name="conteneurNum">
            <option value="0">Tous</option>
            <option value="1">951</option>
            <option value="2">753</option>
            <option value="3">753159</option>
          </select><br />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({
                elementId : '_conteneurNum_id',
                widgetType : 'dijit.form.FilteringSelect',
                widgetAttrs : {
                    hasDownArrow : true
                }
            }));
        </script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found a workaround after some hours wrestling with MyEclipse 2014, Spring 3.1 and old Dojo/Dijit versions, I know this is old but MyEclipse packs these old versions of everything and makes one crazy.

I tried FilteringSelect, Select with null value, html option with value, and replacing dojo libraries which messed the rest of the project. So I'll post this here if it could help anybody:

This case is common if you want a dummy prompt option in your select like '-- Select item --' with a null value. Dojo/dijit version packed with MyEclipse into spring-js-2.3.1.RELEASE, replaces option with null values with separators showed in the dropdown list. In a few last versions of Dojo/Dijit this behaviour seems to be corrected as you can see in the fiddle of Craig Swing.

If the property you bind is not a string, you can assign a single espace as value of dummy option instead of null, because later will be binded as null in the controller, so the dummy option will be showed. Ex:

```
<option selected="selected" value="">Tous</option>
```

But if the property is a String, this way you will find with an unwished blank space in the property in your controller.

So I finally opted to directly modify Select.js

Place it in your project in webapps/resources/dijit/form/Select.js Comment this lines:

```
/*
if(!_1.value){
return new dijit.MenuSeparator();
}else{
*/
var _2=dojo.hitch(this,"_setValueAttr",_1);
var _3=new dijit.MenuItem({option:_1,label:_1.label,onClick:_2,disabled:_1.disabled||false});
dijit.setWaiRole(_3.focusNode,"listitem");
return _3;
/*
}
*/
```

And don't forget to override this path for Resource Servlet in web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>My Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/dijit/form/Select.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```